# How to count multiple rows with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to have the query count the total number of players at the location if they're at the same location, and online. But my current query is returning 0. Not sure what to try, been stuck for a few days.

```
<?php 
    include('connect.php'); 

            $town = $info['location'];

            $grabTown = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `name` = '$town'");
            $t = mysql_fetch_array($grabTown);

            $totPlayers = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS player_total FROM `user_info` WHERE `location` = '$town' AND 'online' = '1'");
            $totalPlayers = mysql_fetch_array($totPlayers);
            $playersTotal = $totalPlayers['player_total'];
?>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the first query?

Comment: Does `user_info.location` really contain the town name, or does it contain the `id` from the `location` table?

Comment: Please show some sample table contents and the expected results.

Comment: user_info.location is the town name, not the id.

Say if there's 10 players online, and 3 are at the same location, it should return 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$totPlayers = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS player_total FROM `user_info` WHERE `location` = '$town' AND `online` = '1'");
```

You had "online" in quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: ^ This solved my problem. Derp.

Thanks!

Comment: @Segarac if so, please hit the check mark by my answer. If you want you can give me an upvote also.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PHP's mysql_* functions is dying, switch to something like mysqli or pdo or whatever. Check my comments in the code I submitted.
Tell me if it works. Cheers.

```
include('connect.php'); 

$town = $info['location'];

$grabTown = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `name` = '$town'");

// Added error check
if (!$grabTown) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$t = mysql_fetch_array($grabTown);

// Changed '' to `` on { 'online' } and removed '' from { '1' }
// Don't know if removing '' on { '1' } is required. I think it's fine either way.
$totPlayers = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS player_total FROM `user_info` WHERE `location` = '$town' AND `online` = 1");

// Added error check
if (!$totPlayers) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$totalPlayers = mysql_fetch_array($totPlayers);
$playersTotal = $totalPlayers['player_total'];
```

Comment: When inserting numbers you're fine either with or without the quotes - You should clarify your first sentance though. MySQL is certainly not dying - it's the most widely used RDB in the world, it's just PHP's `mysql_*` functions that are "dying".